# Editing JPEG file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, background

I saved my Photoshop file as JPEG and when I open it as psd file I only see one layer.

I'm unable to edit text etc.

Comment: You can not open a JPG image as a PSD one. It is still a JPG image. To have a PSD you must save as PSD.

Answer (score 2):

When an image is saved as a JPEG, the image saved will follow the constraints of the [JFIF File Interchange Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) which among other parameters, requires that the image be a single layer in raster form.

This means all features implemented by the image editor will be consolidated and no longer available in the manner you describe.

It's good practice to save your work in the editor program's native format, which will maintain the layers and other features you've used, allowing you to modify it in the future.

Use JPEG format for a more universal distribution form, although better results may be available in formats such as PNG or others.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot help, you are the only one who has your computer.

If the original PSD vesion has existed as a SAVED file, but deleted, then you have a theoretical possiblity to recover it from the trashcan or by using file recovery software.

If the file hasn't ever been saved as PSD, then you are practically in a hopeless situation, the single layer JPG is all you have, opening it as PSD does not generate the rasterized and merged layer's, JPG contains only the rasterized and merged data.

Actually the JPG isn't all you have, you can remember what the PSD contained and that makes possible to remake it.